# Lightbox 2 FullScreen

Tags: lightbox2

I Use the Lightbox 2 of Lokesh Dhakar.

All Options work well and the result is looking good. but my problem is, the overlay is only inside the iframe, not filling the page.

can someone help ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My guess is that it's likely something simple with CSS, but I have no clue as you did not share any of your code.